# ExtJS 4 - Reuse components in MVC architecture

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a list of users and if I click on an item in this list, a window opens. This is the same window for each user, and it's possible to have several window open at the same time. The window shows user informations so for this components I have the same store and the same model.

But if I load data in a specific window, I load the same data in all other open windows.

```
Ext.define('Cc.view.absence.Grid', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.absencegrid',

  border:false,

  initComponent: function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {
      store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Cc.model.Absence',
        autoLoad: false,
        proxy: {
          type: 'ajax',
          reader: {
            type: 'json'
          }
        }
      }),
      columns: [
        {header: 'Du', dataIndex: 'startdate', flex: 3, renderer: this.formatDate},
        {header: 'Au', dataIndex: 'enddate', flex: 3, renderer: this.formatDate},
        {header: 'Exercice', dataIndex: 'year', align: 'center', flex: 1},
        {header: 'Statut', xtype:'templatecolumn', tpl:'<img src="../images/status-{statusid}.png" alt="{status}" title="{status}" />', align: 'center', flex: 1},
        {header: 'Type d\'absence', dataIndex: 'absencetype', align: 'center', flex: 2},
        {header: 'Commentaires', dataIndex: 'comment', flex: 6}
      ],
      dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        items: [
          { xtype: 'tbfill'},
          { xtype: 'button', text: 'Rafraichir', action: 'refresh', iconCls: 'item-rafraichir' }
        ]
      }]
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
  },

  formatDate: function(date) {
    if (!date) {
      return '';
    }
    return Ext.Date.format(date, 'l d F Y - H:i');
  }

});
```

my controller :

```
Ext.define('Cc.controller.Absences', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

  models: ['Absence', 'AbsenceHistory'],

  views: [],

  refs: [
    { ref: 'navigation', selector: 'navigation' },
    { ref: 'tabPanel', selector: 'tabpanel' },
    { ref: 'absencePanel', selector: 'absencepanel' },
    { ref: 'refreshButton', selector: 'absencepanel button[action=refresh]'},
    { ref: 'absenceGrid', selector: 'absencegrid' },
    { ref: 'absenceHistory', selector: 'absencehistory' },
  ],

  init: function() {
    this.control({
      'absencepanel button[action=refresh]': {
        click: this.onClickRefreshButton
      },
      'absencegrid': {
        selectionchange: this.viewHistory
      },
      'absencegrid > tableview': {
        refresh: this.selectAbsence
      },
    });
  },

  selectAbsence: function(view) {
    var first = this.getAbsenceGrid().getStore().getAt(0);
    if (first) {
      view.getSelectionModel().select(first);
    }
  },

  viewHistory: function(grid, absences) {
    var absence = absences[0],
      store = this.getAbsenceHistory().getGrid().getStore();
    if(absence.get('id')){
      store.getProxy().url = '/absence/' + absence.get('id') +'/history';
      store.load();
    }
  },

  onClickRefreshButton: function(view, record, item, index, e){
    var store = this.getAbsenceGrid().getStore();
    store.load();
  },
});
```

other controller which create only one instance of absence.Panel :

```
Ext.define('Cc.controller.Tools', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

  stores: ['Tools', 'User' ],

  models: ['Tool'],

  views: [],

  refs: [
    { ref: 'navigation', selector: 'navigation' },
    { ref: 'tabPanel', selector: 'tabpanel' },
    { ref: 'toolList', selector: 'toollist' },
    { ref: 'toolData', selector: 'toollist dataview' }
  ],

  init: function() {
    this.control({
      'toollist dataview': {
        itemclick: this.loadTab
      },
    });
  },

  onLaunch: function() {
    var dataview = this.getToolData(),
        store = this.getToolsStore();

    dataview.bindStore(store);
  },

  loadTab: function(view, record, item, index, e){
    var tabPanel = this.getTabPanel();
    switch (record.get('tab')) {
      case 'absences':
        if(Ext.getCmp('absence-panel')){
          tabPanel.setActiveTab(Ext.getCmp('absence-panel'));
        }
        else {
          var panel = Ext.create('Cc.view.absence.Panel',{
            id: 'absence-panel'
          }),
              store = panel.getGrid().getStore();
          panel.enable();
          tabPanel.add(panel);
          tabPanel.setActiveTab(panel);
          store.getProxy().url = '/person/' + this.getUserId() +'/absences';
          store.load();
        }
      break;

      default: 
      break;
    }
  },

  getUserId: function(){
    var userStore = this.getUserStore();
    var id = userStore.first().get('id')
    return id;
  }
});
```

the other controller which create many instances of absence.Panel :

```
Ext.define('Cc.controller.Agents', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

  stores: ['Agents'],

  models: ['Agent', 'Absence', 'AbsenceHistory'],

  views: ['agent.List', 'agent.Window', 'absence.Panel', 'absence.Grid', 'absence.History'],
  refs: [
    { ref: 'agentList', selector: 'agentlist' },
    { ref: 'agentData', selector: 'agentlist dataview' },
    { ref: 'agentWindow', selector: 'agentwindow' },
  ],

  init: function() {
    this.control({
      'agentlist dataview':{
        itemclick: this.loadWindow
      },
    });
  },

  onLaunch: function() {
    var dataview = this.getAgentData(),
        store = this.getAgentsStore();
    dataview.bindStore(store);
  },

  loadWindow: function(view, record, item, index, e){
    if(!Ext.getCmp('agent-window'+record.get('id'))){
      var window = Ext.create('Cc.view.agent.Window', {
        title: 'À propos de '+record.get('firstname')+' '+record.get('lastname'),
        id: 'agent-window'+record.get('id')
      }),
          tabPanel = window.getTabPanel();
          absencePanel = window.getAbsencePanel();
          store = absencePanel.getGrid().getStore();

      absencePanel.enable();
      tabPanel.add(absencePanel);
      tabPanel.setActiveTab(absencePanel);
      store.getProxy().url = '/person/' + record.get('id') +'/absences';
      store.load();
    }
    Ext.getCmp('agent-window'+record.get('id')).show();
  }
});
```

and the absence.Panel view, container of absence.Grid :

```
Ext.define('Cc.view.absence.Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.absencepanel',

  title: 'Mes absences',
  iconCls: 'item-outils',
  closable: true,
  border: false,
  disabled: true,
  layout: 'border',

  initComponent: function() {
    this.grid = Ext.create('Cc.view.absence.Grid', {
      region: 'center'
    });
    this.history = Ext.create('Cc.view.absence.History', {
      region: 'south',
      height: '25%'
    });
        Ext.apply(this, {
      items: [
        this.grid,
        this.history
      ]
    });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

  getGrid: function(){
    return this.grid;
  },

  getHistory: function(){
    return this.history;
  }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a unique instance of each window when the user clicks on the item? Right now I think you are just opening duplicates?

Comment: Same store is link to all window. So if I load data into a new window, all other open windows are reloaded too. But I want to reload data only If I click on the refresh button.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Here is more details explanation of what I am doing. I hope you have read the forum completely. There is still one information that we are not clear about. That is the exact use of using "stores" property in controller. IMHO Sencha team should explain the MVC in much more detail with complex examples.

Yes, what you have newly posted is correct. when you have create new view, create a new instance of the store! Now, from the forum discussions, people argue about MVC. I would definitly go with [steffenk](http://www.sencha.com/forum/member.php?7207-steffenk) . What we are doing here is injecting a new instance of store to my view. And I am ignoring the `stores` property of the controller.

Here is an example:

This is my view. Its a panel (with user profile information) that I display on my tabpanel :

```
Ext.define('Dir.view.profile.View' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.profileview',
    title : 'Profile',
    profileId: 1,   // default and dummy value
    initComponent: function() {

        // configure necessary stuff, I access my store etc here..       
        // console.log(this.profileStore);
        this.callParent(arguments);         
    },
    // Other view methods goes here
});
```

Now, look at my controller:

```
Ext.define('Dir.controller.Profile', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    //stores: ['Profile'],   --> Note that I am NOT using this!
    refs: [     
        {ref:'cp',selector: 'centerpane'}
    ],
    views: ['profile.View'],
    init: function() {
        // Do your init tasks if required
    },  
    displayProfile: function(selectedId) {

            // create a new store.. pass your config, proxy url etc..
        var store = Ext.create('Dir.store.Profile',{profileId: selectedId});

        console.log('Display Profile for ID ' + selectedId);    

        // Create instance of my view and pass the new store
        var view = Ext.widget('profileview',{profileId: selectedId,profileStore: store});

        // Add my new view to centeral panel and display it...
        this.getCp().add(view);
        this.getCp().setActiveTab(view);
    }
});
```

My `displayProfile()` is called from some event listeners (Menu, Tree etc) and it passes a id. My controller using this id to setup a new store and view. I hope the above code gives you a clear picture of what I said yesterday.

In your controller, you will have to add `Ext.require('Dir.store.Profile');` so that ExtJS know you have such a store. This is because we are not making use of `stores` property.

Now, you can want to reuse these created stores elsewhere, you can add them to the [StoreManager](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.StoreManager). With this, you can access your created stores at any place, add and remove stores. But this comes with a overhead of you managing the instances of the store.

---

Why do you share the same instance of the store with different views? when you have a new view, create a new instance of the store. This will prevent updated data appearing on other windows when one is refreshed.

Comment: I don't know if you really understand me. It's exactly the same problem here : [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132934-Views-in-MVC-are-not-reusable&highlight=storeid). how do you will fix this problem ?

Comment: I defined a view like on my first post (edit). So when I call `Ext.create('Cc.view.absence.Panel')`, I create as many views as stores ?

Comment: yes, have a look at the updated answer.. I hope this helps you in understanding what I was trying to explain.

Comment: Ok thank you, but I really don't understand why in my version, store is independant of my view if I use `Ext.create(...)`

Comment: "store is independent of my view" --> I didn't get that. can you explain how its behaving independent?

Comment: If I define store in my view, like my exemple above (I am ignoring the stores property of the controller like you). Why when I've two or more instances of this view, store still the same (when I reload one, it also reload all other).

Comment: ah! thats because you are using the stores property. When you use it, the controller create a single instance of the store and put it in StoreManager. When you create any number of views, the view simply picks the store from StoreManager (in our case, for n views its the same store). So, if you change the store's data.. it changes in all the views you have.

Comment: have a look at the updated question, I think I don't use stores property.

Comment: can you show me how you create a new view? there should be some scope issue.. i cannot think of any other issue..

Comment: So I have two controllers that create instances of the view. Tool controller create only one instance and Agent controller create few others.

Comment: going through your code, I don't see where you create the grid(absencegrid)! I am sure, you are having a scoping problem in your code which gives you the same store all the time

Comment: look at my view Cc.view.absence.Panel in initComponent function

Comment: why do you create a grid in init? you should be creating a new view when you need to display the grid upon. ie, when user request for Absence grid right? And when you create a new grid, you should also create a new store. look at my code above.

Comment: I create grid in init because my panel is composed of two grid. Why I could not create them in the init function ??

Comment: so, i guess each time you create `Cc.view.agent.Window` you are also creating a new `absencepanel`? check with firebug or chrome tool how many panels are getting created

Comment: Yes each time I create Window I am also creating a new absencepanel. Sorry, I forgot to mention it. I don't know where to put the breakpoints to have all components in my application. However I put one after the creation of absencepanel and it's impossible for me to determine if the store is unique or not.

Comment: All the methods that refresh all the grids are in the Absence controller. When I call load() from the store outside of the controller, no problems. Have a look at onClickRefreshButton and viewHistory functions above.

So I think error is in `this.getAbsenceGrid()` that return all the absencegrid I create ??

Comment: yup.. i did see that and that is confusing me a lot! you will have to debug and check if getAbsenceGrid always return the same grid..hence returning the same store. To avoid that, see that you properly scope your button(refresh button).

Comment: getAbsenceGrid always return the same grid, hence returning the same store as you said. Only the first panel I create is refresh. But I don't really know how to see that I properly scope my refresh button.

Comment: honestly, need to look deeper into it..Will be working on similar stuff in a few days.. so lets see..

Comment: Have a look at this post as well :http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134187-View-lt-gt-Controller-calling-issues

Comment: Haha! :D I wonder why non from the dev team is in action for those questions.

Comment: I poke @sencha and @edspencer on twitter but Ed Spencer just answer once.

Comment: so did I! but I didn't see ed's response in forum.. he responded thru twitter?

Comment: no just once : "there's a lot we could do with docs - what's the biggest pain point for you right now?"

Comment: Do you have any news about my problem ?

Comment: @kyrillos, you definitely have scoping problem. My application works fine. For troubleshooting your issue, I suggest you reduce the complexity of the code and gradually add functionality to the application..

Comment: My code is not complicated, I have only 2 instances of a view with a controler, that's all. With a button to refresh.

Comment: I am not talking about that "complexity".. i am asking you to strip off some code.. use one one functionality, test it, and then add next functionality..

Comment: Yes, but the only one functionality is the refresh of the grid.

Comment: I think my problem is about the ref system : `{ ref: 'tabPanel', selector: 'tabpanel' }`. If I call `getTabPanel()`, I retrieve in fact always the same tabpanel.